# What's an extensive solution for detecting os, browser and version-number in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm basically looking for an extension or a function that covers most browsers and operating systems from a user-agent.

Comment: With recent versions of IE, this became very difficult.

Comment: I've used this in the past https://github.com/darcyclarke/Detect.js

Comment: There are thousands of user agent strings, and the list is growing constantly. Maybe something like [*User Agent String.Com*](http://useragentstring.com) or [*User agents.org*](http://www.user-agents.org) will do the job. But don't use them for anything other than statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use one of the many mobile-detection libraries available.

One such project is [mobile-detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobile-detect).

Apparently, it gives you all the information you need. From it's README:

```
var md = new MobileDetect(
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-in; SonyEricssonMT11i' +
    ' Build/4.1.A.0.562) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko)' +
    ' Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30');

// more typically we would instantiate with 'window.navigator.userAgent'
// as user-agent; this string literal is only for better understanding

console.log( md.mobile() );          // 'Sony'
console.log( md.phone() );           // 'Sony'
console.log( md.tablet() );          // null
console.log( md.userAgent() );       // 'Safari'
console.log( md.os() );              // 'AndroidOS'
console.log( md.is('iPhone') );      // false
console.log( md.is('bot') );         // false
console.log( md.version('Webkit') );         // 534.3
console.log( md.versionStr('Build') );       // '4.1.A.0.562'
console.log( md.match('playstation|xbox') ); // false
```

Also, consider if using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) isn't more appropriate. Feature detection is more robust and future-proof than device-checking.

Comment: I don't see the browser in my Samsung TV anywhere…

Comment: I just edited adding the recommendation to use modernizr for precisely this reason. It's hard to keep up with all the crazy browsers now.